# How to add data in same file in Apache PIG?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to PIG.

Actually I have a use case in which I have to store the data again and again in the same file after every regular interval. But as I gone through some tutorial and links, I didn't see the anything related to this.

How should I do store the data in same file?

Comment: What do you mean store the data again and again ? Could you give the details, in which case you need to store the data again and again

Comment: @zjffdu: I mean after processing some logic whatever data I will get, I want to insert in same file. Base line is that like in SQL we use INSERT query, same kind of behaviour I want to implement here in my case.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible. Pig uses Hadoop and right now there is no "recommended" solution for appending files.

The other point is that pig would produce one file only if one mapper has been used or one reducer has been used and the end of the whole data flow.

You can:

1. Give more info about the problem you are trying to solve
2. Bad solution:

2.1. process data in your pig script

2.2. load data from exisitng file

2.3. union relations hwre first relation keeps new data, the second relation keeps data from exisitng file

2.4. store union result to new output

2.5. replace old file with new one.

Good solution:

Create folder /mydata

create partitions inside folder, they can be /yyyy/MM/dd/HH if you do process data each hour

Use globs to read data:

```
/mydata/*/*/*/*/*
```

All files from hour partitions would be read by PIG/HIVE/MR or whatever hadoop tool.

Comment: Yeah I did it in a same way, but I am expecting it in more effcient way. Anyways, Thanks for your reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

make a date folder like: **/abc/hadoop/20130726/**
within you generate output based on timestamp like: **/abc/hadoop/20130726/201307265465.gz**.

Then use **getmerge** command to merge all data into a single file

```
Usage: hadoop fs -getmerge <src> <localdst> [addnl]
```

Hope it will help you.